# WebClient openWrite not writing until it is closed

Tags: c#, .net, stream, webclient, flush

I'm using a WebClient to send raw bytes to a web server. The web server knows what to do with those raw bytes. However the WebClient doesn't actually send the data to the server until the call to w.Close() on the last line. **I would like to send the data every time w.Flush() is called.** Is that possible?

```
        string filename = "C:\\blah.dat";
        byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Stream w = wc.OpenWrite("http://localhost:80/files/");

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            w.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            w.Flush();
        }

        w.Close();
```

p.s I'm not interested in UploadFile. I'm just using the file's byte[] as sample binary data.

Comment: First of all, dispose your objects, secondly, look at `AutoFlush`, thirdly: should you really be uploading the same content 10 times?

Comment: Thanks Oscar. I do have a using statement in there now. AutoFlush is a property of StreamWriter which doesn't write binary. The 10 times is just a simulation of sending multiple chunks. In reality this wouldn't be a file's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of `HttpWebClient` is to buffer all the data, determine its length and use that to set the `Content-Length` in HTTP request headers.

For most people, the correct answer nowadays is to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) which was introduced in .NET framework 4.5.

For those of us still using .NET framework v3.5, here are two alternatives:

- Set the `Content-Length` before opening the request stream. This cannot be done directly through `WebClient`, and we need to create the `HttpWebRequest` object manually. This code sends data byte-per-byte as an example:

```
byte[] data = ...;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/plain";
req.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    stream.Write(data, i, 1);
    stream.Flush()
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
stream.Close();
```

- Set `SendChunked` to `true` in `HttpWebRequest` to use the [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Be aware that it has some [bugs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/webclient-synchronus-cunked-sending-sends-wrong-by/277154) which affect the `bufferOffset` argument to stream `Write()` method.